# Facebook login error if a add pages_user_* in scope

Tags: facebook, fbsdk

I'm using FB js sdk.
In the function FB.login, if I add one of this permission (pages_user_locale, pages_user_gender,  pages_user_timezone) I have this error.
If I remove them, the fb login work fine.

[image: 1]

Example of code:

```
FB.login((loginResponse) => {
...
}, { scope: "public_profile,email,pages_messaging,pages_messaging_phone_number,pages_show_list,pages_manage_metadata,instagram_basic,instagram_manage_messages,pages_read_engagement,business_management,catalog_management,pages_user_locale,pages_user_gender,pages_user_timezone", return_scopes: true });
```

Comment: I found the mistake.
This permission  shouldn't request these page permissions using FB Login. 
As long as they are approved at app and page level, I should be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake.
This permission  shouldn't request these page permissions using FB Login.
As long as they are approved at app and page level, I should be able to use it.